# Fire onclick event for asp form load in Firefox, using Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, events, asp-classic, onclick

I'd like to use a bookmarklet to fire an onclick event for an ASP form load.
The code for the onclick event is:

```
    Onclick=”parent.content.location.href='/ics/tt/ticketNew.asp';”
```

I thought this would work:

```
    Javascript:parent.content.location.href='/ics/tt/ticketNew.asp';
```

But no dice...

I can get a different onclick event to fire with a bookmarklet. I can get this:

```
    onclick="menuClick('ticket', null, ''); "
```

To fire with this:

```
    javascript:parent.menu.menuClick('ticket');
```

Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: you sure your initial approach works? also you should write javascript in lowercase (just in case you didn't )

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm going to try a different method to make the onclick event fire. The element contains a small png image, that performs the same action when clicked. The problem is, it doesn't have an ID. It has an alt tag though. Here is the code for the image element: <img border="0" align="absmiddle" style="HEIGHT:16px; WIDTH:16px;" alt="New Ticket" src="/ics/inc/css/parature/images/icons/iTicketNew.png"></img>
Maybe I could use Javascript to get the src of the image and use ".click()"

Comment: "parent.content." implies you are working in frames or iframes. Could problems be due to cross-domain issue? If iframe you may need to look at the SANDBOX attribute of the IFRAME tag.

Answer (score 0):

Well guys thanks for your advice. What I ended up doing was using an autohotkey script to accomplish what I needed. In AHK I used Firefox shortcut keys to set the zoom to default so that my click coordinates in AHK lined up perfectly. No need for simulating the onclick event although it would have been more elegant.